# Slide a div before a fadetoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently working on a site mainly with php, i really know little to none when it comes to javascript jquery. i do have something working were i press a button and i fade a div in. But it abruptly moves divs under it.. is there a way were i can slide the divs under it before the fade in? heres my current code.. and a link to the page. clicking on send message starts the fade.

http://www.mxbempire.com/?page=rider&riderid=17&id=1#

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#composemsg').hide();

    $('.msgdwn').click(function(){
        $('#composemsg').fadeToggle("slow");
    });

    $('.msgdwn').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

and the divs

```
<div class="lowerhalf">

    <div class="card2" id="composemsg">
        <div class="heading">Send Message to <?php echo $ridertag ?></div>
        <textarea name="message" id="compose"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="message" value="Send PM" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <div class="card2">
        <div class="heading">Wall Comments</div>

    </div>
    <div class="card2">
        <div class="heading">Screenshots</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card2">
        <div class="heading">Statistics</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
$(function(){

    $('.msgdwn').click(function(){
        $('#composemsg').slideDown(500, function(){
            $('#composemsg').animate({ opacity : 1 }, 1000);
        });
    });    

});
```

In addition with some CSS like this:

```
.composemsg {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

See an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cp6mx/

Comment: This is great, slightly jumpy on roll out, is there a way i can set it to toggle it back closed?

Comment: http://www.mxbempire.com/?page=rider&riderid=17

Working! Thankyou so much for your help, people don't have to ever reply so i appreciate you taking the time to help.

Do these functions not take into consideration padding or margins? as it seems the slide jumps to a certain location and back, if you notice on the link you will see what I mean when you click send msg.

Comment: I was able to fix the jumping by removing the min-height attribute on the divs that actually slide.

Comment: Btw, margin wouldn't be included in the `slideDown/slideUp` afaik. It would jump at the very end of the animation when the element is actually set to `display:none;`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to join the 2 click-handlers into one function... No point in having 2 different here

```
$('.msgdwn').click(function(){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('#composemsg').fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Then I am not really sure what you want to do... the header says slide but you don't specify it in your question.... so assuming that you want to slide out the box (which makes not a lot of sense, because if you first slide it out and then fade it out nobody will see the fadeout) ...

But just to explain what you asked in the heading... if you want to perform an action after another action finished, you just need to use a callback function which is very easy with jQuery
e.g.

```
$('#composemsg').fadeToggle("slow",function(){
   alert('now disappeared');
});

or 
$('#composemsg').slideToggle("slow",function(){
   $(this).fadeToggle("slow");  // This now referring to the object the first function was attached to
});
```

If you want to do both at the same time you could use animate to have both at the same time:

```
$('#composemsg').animate({
  height: "toggle",
  opacity: "toggle"
});
```

Comment: Sorry to not be clear, When the main div fades in it pushes other divs out of the way in an instant, it looks very bad. So i wanted to slide downward the other divs before the main div started fading in. and once faded out slide other divs slide back up